# Android database no such column error?

Tags: android, database

I'm using eclipse ADT to create and android ap and I'm in the middle of trying to create a sql database. however I keep getting a "E/SQLiteLog(786): (1) no such column: location" error dispite the fact that Ive included it in the database creation class, any ideas?

code for the database creation class:

```
    package com.example.networkassignment;


    import android.content.ContentValues; 
    import android.content.Context; 
    import android.database.Cursor; 
    import android.database.SQLException; 
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 
    import android.util.Log; 
        public class DB 

        { 
                public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location"; 
                public static final String KEY_DATE = "date"; 
                public static final String KEY_SUPPORT = "support"; 
                public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id"; 

                private static final String TAG = "DB"; 
                private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper; 
                private SQLiteDatabase mDb; 

                /** 
                 * Database creation sql statement 
                 */ 

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
        "create table shows (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                + "location text not null, date text not null, support text not null);"; 


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data"; 
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "shows"; 
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; 

private final Context mCtx; 

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{ 
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    } 
 @Override 
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    { 
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); 
    }


 @Override 
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    { 
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "  + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data"); 
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS shows"); 
        onCreate(db); 
    } 

} 
public DB(Context ctx) 
{ 
 this.mCtx = ctx; 
} 


public DB open() throws SQLException 
{ 
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx); 
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    return this; 
} 

public void close() 
{ 
    mDbHelper.close(); 
} 

public long createShow(String location, String date, String support) 
{ 
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
    initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location); 
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date); 
    initialValues.put(KEY_SUPPORT, support); 
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues); 
} 

public boolean deleteShow(long rowId)
{ 

 return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; 
 } 


public Cursor fetchAllShows()
{   
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_LOCATION, 
          KEY_DATE, KEY_SUPPORT}, null, null, null, null, null); 
} 

public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException { 

    Cursor mCursor = 

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, 
                    KEY_LOCATION, KEY_DATE,KEY_SUPPORT }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, 
                    null, null, null, null); 
    if (mCursor != null)
    { 
        mCursor.moveToFirst(); 
    } 
 return mCursor; 

 } 


public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String Location, String Date, String Support) 
{ 
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues(); 
    args.put(KEY_LOCATION, Location ); 
    args.put(KEY_DATE, Date); 
    args.put(KEY_SUPPORT, Support); 

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; 
} 

        }
```

and for the class that uses it

```
package com.example.networkassignment;


import android.app.ListActivity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.ContextMenu; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter; 
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class database extends ListActivity 
{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0; 
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1; 
    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST; 
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1; 

    private DB mDbHelper; 
    private Cursor mNotesCursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.database);
        mDbHelper = new DB(this); 
        mDbHelper.open(); 
        fillData(); 


        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

        private void fillData()
        { 
            mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllShows(); 
            startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor); 

            String[] from = new String[]{DB.KEY_LOCATION, DB.KEY_DATE, DB.KEY_SUPPORT}; 

            // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1) 
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txtLocation, R.id.txtDate, R.id.txtSupport};

            // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display 
            SimpleCursorAdapter shows = 
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.show_row, mNotesCursor, from, to); 
            setListAdapter(shows); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        { 
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
            menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert); 
            return true; 
        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) 
        { 
            switch(item.getItemId()) { 
            case INSERT_ID: 
                createNote(); 
                return true; 
            } 

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
        { 
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 
            menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
        { 
            switch(item.getItemId())
            { 
            case DELETE_ID: 
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); 
                mDbHelper.deleteShow(info.id); 
                fillData(); 
                return true; 
            } 
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item); 
        } 

        private void createNote() 
        { 
            Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowEdit.class); 
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE); 
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
        { 
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 
                Cursor c = mNotesCursor; 
                c.moveToPosition(position); 
                Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowEdit.class); 
                i.putExtra(DB.KEY_ROWID, id);
                i.putExtra(DB.KEY_LOCATION, c.getString( c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.KEY_LOCATION))); 
                i.putExtra(DB.KEY_DATE, c.getString( c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.KEY_DATE))); 
                i.putExtra(DB.KEY_SUPPORT, c.getString( c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.KEY_SUPPORT))); 
                startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT); 
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { 
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); 
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
                switch(requestCode) { 
                    case ACTIVITY_CREATE: 
                        String location = extras.getString(DB.KEY_LOCATION); 
                        String date = extras.getString(DB.KEY_DATE); 
                        String support = extras.getString(DB.KEY_SUPPORT); 
                        mDbHelper.createShow(location, date, support); 
                        fillData(); 
                        break; 
                    case ACTIVITY_EDIT: 
                        Long rowId = extras.getLong(DB.KEY_ROWID); 
                        if (rowId != null) { 
                            String editLocation = extras.getString(DB.KEY_LOCATION); 
                            String editDate = extras.getString(DB.KEY_DATE);
                            String editSupport = extras.getString(DB.KEY_SUPPORT); 
                            mDbHelper.updateNote(rowId, editLocation, editDate, editSupport); 
                        } 
                        fillData(); 
                        break; 
                } 
            } 

}
```

EDIT: accidentlly put up the DB class of an older version....

Answer (score 0):

You are passing statically a table name while creating a table

```
create table events
```

That's your mistake. While accessing the table you are using variable `DATABASE_TABLE`. In short you are creating table with name 'events' but when you are inserting data you are trying to insert data into 'shows' table which is actually not created.

To solve this problem just update your create table query as follows,

```
"create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " 
            + "location text not null, date text not null, support text not null);";
```

After doing this delete your old application and run a fresh code.

Comment: I changed it to the above but I'm still getting the "no such column" error

Answer (score 0):

in create table statement is creating problem:

```
create table events (_id integer primary key autoincrement,location text not null, date text not null, support text not null)
```

use this on directly...no need to **concatenate** the data..That concatenating is creating the problems...